# Need to track what websites a user visits after leaving my site

Tags: cookies, browser

I would like to track what websites my site's visitors go to after they leave.

Would it be possible to place a cookie on their browser when they visit my site, and then later if they go to Facebook.com or stackoverflow.com, my cookie will retreive the browser's URL data and send it back to my server.

I could then look at this data and know that my visitors had gone to Facebook.com and stackoverflow.com after they left my site.

Is this possible using cookies?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Separate from whether this is possible - it's not, unless you own an ad network, and only then if your users' browsers are configured in a particular way - this is an awful thing for you to want to do, and you should reevaluate your motivations.

Comment: have you tried anything??

Comment: It's not always a useful path, @hexalys, but I believe it was useful here. I haven't downvoted and I haven't voted to close, for the reasons you listed. But I have noted to the OP that what they're looking to do is "bad", for lack of another word besides the ones I used, and they should stop and think again.

Answer (score 2):

No. Cookies are not executed or anything. They are just dumb bits of data.

You would need to be able to execute code on the page they are visiting afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

What I presume you are trying to ask, is that you want to track your outbound links.

This is mainly done with Javascript: You need to intercept click events from outbound anchor links, and send an event notification [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21660351/1647538), or using the [hitCallbackmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18537807/1647538) prior to completing the redirection to the external website. For Google Analytics see [documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en). Or you could do via a custom JS implementation sending the info back to your server instead.

Alternatively your could replace all outbound links on the server side in your html source, and have all links pointed to your server first, and redirected to the external sites. But using redirects for this purpose is not really a good recommendation, unless you are an ad networks or a search engine company requiring such method.

Lastly, there is an alternative method using the [HTML5 'ping' attribute](http://www.sitepoint.com/new-html5-attributes-hyperlinks-download-media-ping/). But the feature has been [either removed and/or not yet fully implemented across all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22434264/1647538) as of this writing.

But you can't track where your visitors go beyond the 1st level outbound links of your site.