# How cross browser is the ping attribute of anchor elements?

Tags: html, cross-browser

`<a ping="...">` is a relatively new, relatively unknown attribute in HTML5's anchor element.

How cross-browser compliant is it?

I've looked at online sources like MDN and http://caniuse.com, but found nothing that suggest browser support.

I want to know if it's a viable option for link tracking today in 2014.

Comment: For reference: The [`ping` attribute is part of WHATWG’s *HTML*](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#ping), but not (yet?) of [W3C’s *HTML 5.1 Nightly*](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/).

Comment: Is the `ping` attribute actually a `ping`? As I understand, people don't use `ping`s anymore, and w3schools says the attribute sends `HTTP` `Post` requests. There are better ways to do what `ping` does, I wonder if the `ping` attribute can do those instead of `ping`ing?

Comment: caniuse now includes this feature: http://caniuse.com/#feat=ping

Comment: BTW, as of 2019, [Chrome/ium, Safari and others do have this enabled by default and do not even allow disabling anymore](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/major-browsers-to-prevent-disabling-of-click-tracking-privacy-risk/), only Firefox does not even have it enabled by default.

Comment: @rugk "Mozilla has told BleepingComputer that they will be enabling the tracking feature called hyperlink auditing, or Pings, by default in Firefox." ([link](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/software/mozilla-firefox-to-enable-hyperlink-ping-tracking-by-default/)) (April 19, 2019)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The `ping` attribute was included in pre-W3C drafts of HTML5. It remained in W3C drafts of HTML5 up until early 2010 - the last draft to include it was [W3C Working Draft 4 March 2010](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100304/); the next draft was [W3C Working Draft 24 June 2010](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/).

Why was it removed? It was [massively unpopular](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2007Nov/thread.html#msg42) - an HTML feature designed for advertisers to track clicks on adverts. Hixie's argument was that they can already do that; `ping` just made the process more transparent. And browsers would be able to offer a feature to block `ping` tracking. The counter-argument to that is that if browsers had this feature, publishers would avoid `ping`, it being unreliable compared to current click-tracking techniques.

Some browsers support it because of a combination of:

- They implemented it early, and haven't felt a need to remove it; and
- They support the WHATWG spec instead of or as well as the W3C spec.

Browsers that support it seem to be **Safari** and **Chrome**. (It's no surprise that the latter does; it originally used Safari's WebKit as its layout engine, and now uses Blink, a fork of WebKit.) **Firefox** also supports it, but since 2008, support has been disabled by default - it can be enabled through about:config, though I don't suppose many people do.

**Internet Explorer** [does not support it (yet?)](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/793755/ie11-feature-request-support-for-the-ping-attribute-on-a). **Opera 12.x** does not support the attribute, but I haven't checked in Opera's next generation of Blink-based browsers.

Answer (score 17):

You can also see the support with the Wikipedia article *[Comparison of layout engines (HTML5)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29)* for [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit), [Gecko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gecko_%28layout_engine%29), etc.

It appears to be a potential privacy invasive attribute as well, being able to send data to third parties. It is disabled by default in the browsers that support it.

Note: as *null* said, this post has not been updated since 2012!

Comment: How is it any more disruptive of privacy than, say, using javascript to rewrite the destination URL during click?  Or simply sharing the server log with the third party?

Comment: It's not, it's simply another way.

Comment: Maybe the post wasn't updated since 2012 because nothing has changed since then.

Answer (score 2):

According to [deanhume.com](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/improved-tracking-with-the--a-ping--attribute---html5/3098) only [Safari](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29) and [Google Chrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Chrome) supports it and maybe Firefox also supports it because in [their documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) they are not flagged with the warning "This API has not been standardized." So [W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools) may be right :)

Comment: "So W3Schools may be right" statements I rarely here and rarely agree with.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays we have [`navigator.sendBeacon()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) which makes an http request that continues in the background after navigation if needed, and unlike ping, which is not enabled by default in firefox, this method is supported by all major browsers.

Also, fetch requests have 'keepalive' option, which allows them to continue after navigation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Internet Explorer (no surprise) and [Opera](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera_%28web_browser%29) both seem to not like it.

Source: *[HTML <a> ping Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_ping.asp)* ([W3Schools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3Schools))

Comment: Amazing that of all the sources on the web, only the most despicable one has the info I need. Thank you. But which IE are we talking about?  IE8? IE11?

Comment: @SecondRikudo My experience of this site lets me think there's an error in this page...

Comment: I wouldn't rely on W3Schools either

Comment: By the way, IE11 does not support the Ping attribute according to this feature request: http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/793755/ie11-feature-request-support-for-the-ping-attribute-on-a

Comment: @SecondRikudo and others why? what is wrong with w3schools? (sorry for offtopic)

Comment: [This guy](http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/improved-tracking-with-the--a-ping--attribute---html5/3098) and [this article](http://news.softpedia.com/news/Mobile-Google-Search-No-Longer-Redirects-to-a-Google-URL-When-Tapping-a-Result-388426.shtml) state that only Chrome and Safari support it.

Comment: @null note that that blog post was from October 2013

Comment: @RUJordan The relevant section in the wikipedia article you referenced hasn't been updated for a lot longer than that? [Since 2012 in fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)&action=history), and the references used even further back.